Using one dataframe as condition to get a score from other dataframes in R
I have data frame of multiple columns, each row will represent a condition that I want to use in another data frame to collect a score.
the first data frame looks like this:
condition_df <- data.frame(
type = c("3701", "4901", "3701"),
 position = c(51, 22, 13),
subtype = c("M", "D", "E")
)

and the data that I want to apply the condition on is :

df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:5,
  type1 = c("3701", "4901", "4902", "4903", "1501"),
  type2 = c("3801", "4901", "4901","5050","6069"),
  type3 = c("3901", "5001", "8901","5050","6069"),
  type4 = c("4001", "3901", "7901","5050","6069"),
  `51` = c("M", "A", "M", "M", "A"),
  `22` = c("D", "D", "K", "A", "D"),
  `13` = c("E", "G", "E", "E", "G"),
  `55` = c("M", "A", "M", "M", "A"),
  `25` = c("D", "D", "K", "A", "D"),
  `16` = c("E", "G", "E", "E", "G"), check.names = FALSE
)


The idea is if the type(type1:type4) in df does not match type in condition_df, then look for the columns that there number equal to position in condition_df and then count how many letters in that column that match the subtype.
Example is the first line of condition_df, if 3701 is not available in type1 to type4 , then count how many M at column 51. In that case the count will = 2 as we do not count the first M as it for that row the type1 matches type in condition_df.
I want to get the final score for each type in the condition_df, so for the type 3701, we have 2 results, one from column number 51 and one from column number 13, in that case I want to get the sum of these 2 results.
I've tried several ways but it did not work:
df <-df %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(
      !!new_column_name := case_when(
        !any(c_across(type1:type4) == condition_df$type) ~ sum(get(condition_df$position) == condition_df$type),
        TRUE ~ 0))%>%
    ungroup()

The output will be like this:
output_df <- data.frame(
  type = c("3701", "4901", "3701"),
  position = c(51, 22, 13),
  Score = c(2, 2, 2)
)


I'm sorry if my explanation is not clear enough. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Not clear, you say "Example is the first line of condition_df, if 3701 is not available in type1 to type4", but 3701 is available in df type1 1st row. Please clarify and add an expected output for this example datasets.

Hi, yes, this is the condition, when the type is not available across the 4 type columns, then we count the M. in other words, count how many M in column 51 but do not include any M if there is type 3701 in any of the 4 columns of type. Sorry its very complicated i hope I clarified  it.

In your original code, rowwise() is applied to df, not to condition_df, and case_when and c_across did not apply the conditions row-by-row for each specific condition.
Try this
condition_df <- condition_df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    score = sum(!apply(df[, 2:5], 1, function(row) type %in% row) &
                df[[as.character(position)]] == subtype)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

